# Arduino countdown timer preventing rest of program running

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a program that checks to see if an RFID tag has been read, if it has, it runs some code.

I also have a count down timer function (timer) that I'd like to run in the background. It displays the clock on the bottom of the LCD.

The problem I'm having is that when I put timer(); in the main loop, the rest of the program is delayed for the duration of the count down which means that no RFID cards are read.

The timer works, but nothing below timer(); is running.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this? Thank you.

```
    #include <SPI.h>      
#include <MFRC522.h>  
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>


int readflag;
int initstate = 1;

int nextred = 4;
int nextblue = 8;

uint8_t readCard[4];           

int minutes = 1; //start min
int seconds = 0; //start seconds


MFRC522 mfrc522(10, 9);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);


///////////////////////////////////////// Setup ///////////////////////////////////
void setup() {

    //Protocol Configuration
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  SPI.begin();           
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();    
  mfrc522.PCD_SetAntennaGain(mfrc522.RxGain_max);

  lcd.begin(20, 4);


}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Main loop
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void loop () {

 do {                                                             
   readflag = checkread(); 
if (initstate == 0) {
  timer(); //start timer - timer works but nothing below timer(); is running.
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   lcd.print("Red team next: ");
   lcd.print(nextred);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Blue team next: ");
    lcd.print(nextblue);

}
  }
  while (!readflag); 
  tone(8, 850, 15);
  recordid();
  updatenextteamnumbers();
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Function to update team next numbers
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void updatenextteamnumbers() {
//If Blue Tag scanned show team info
  if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0xACB7D573) {

    Serial.println("Blue Tag detected, showing team info");
    initstate=0;

   }


//Red Team (sequence 4, 5, 2, 1, 9)
else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x29FDC9F5 && initstate == 0) {
    Serial.println("CARD 4 detected");
    nextred = 5;

      }

else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x3FCE7832 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 5 detected");
    nextred = 2;

}

else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x3FCCECE2 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 2 detected");
    nextred = 1;

      }


  else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x3F7AB752 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 1 detected");
    nextred = 9;

    //activateredrelay

      }


  else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x00000000 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 9 detected");
    redwins();    

      }



//Blue Team (sequence 8, 6, 3, 7, 10)

else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x00000000 && initstate == 0) {
    Serial.println("CARD 8 detected");
    nextblue = 6;

      }

else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x00000000 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 6 detected");
    nextblue = 3;

}

else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x3F7ABA82 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 3 detected");
    nextblue = 7;

      }


  else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x00000000 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 7 detected");
    nextblue = 10;

    //activatebluerelay

      }


  else if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x00000000 && initstate == 0) {

    Serial.println("CARD 10 detected");
    bluewins();    

      }

 }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Stores the ID of the card that's been detected in readCard byte array
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void recordid() {
    mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent();
    mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial();

    for (int i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) { 
        readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];  
        Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
        }
Serial.println("");
    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  }


/////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns 1 if a card has been detected
/////////////////////////////////////////////
int checkread() {
   if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { 
    return 0; }                                        //no card detected

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); 
    return 1; }                                       //card detected


/////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Runs if red team wins
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void redwins() {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
      lcd.print("Red team wins!");
      lcd.display();
      Serial.println("Red team wins!");
      delay(36000);
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Runs if blue team wins
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void bluewins() {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
      lcd.print("Blue team wins!");
      lcd.display();
      Serial.println("Blue team wins!");
      delay(36000);
}


 /////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Count down timer
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void timer() {
lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("Time left:");
 while (minutes > 0 || seconds >= 0) {
  lcd.setCursor(15, 3);
 (minutes < 10) ? lcd.print("0") : NULL;
 lcd.print(minutes);
 lcd.print(":");
 (seconds < 10) ? lcd.print("0") : NULL;
 lcd.print(seconds);
 lcd.display();
 decrement();
 delay(1000);
 }
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Decrement timer
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void decrement() {
      if (seconds > 0) {
          seconds -= 1;
      } 
      else      {
         if (minutes > 0) {
           seconds = 59;
           minutes -= 1;
          } 
          else  {
            timeup();
          }
       }
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Called when time expires
/////////////////////////////////////////////
void timeup() {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
      lcd.print("Time up!");
      lcd.display();
}
```

Comment: You would better ask this on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/. You can use your http://stackoverflow.com/ account for this, linking it to these communities too. Go to the site, upper right click on "join this community".

Answer (score 0):

The smoking gun here looks to be the following line:

```
while (minutes > 0 || seconds >= 0)
```

When the values of these variables both reach 0, the `decrement` function will no longer modify them. This is a problem since `seconds >= 0` still evaluates as true, therefore causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi @Brian - the counter functions fine - I just need it to run 'in the background'. I've implemented it using millis() (which removed the delay, that is causing the 'blocking' but unfortunately it still won't work.

Comment: @mh512 - I think you may have misunderstood my original answer; it is not the blocking that is causing this to hang, but the line `while (minutes > 0 || seconds >= 0)` will always evaluate true since it stop at 0 minutes, 0 seconds.